# Datatables in Laravel, render component out as button text

Tags: laravel, datatables

Just throwing this out there as a hail mary but can I add a SVG component in as the text to a dataTable?

Instead of -

```
$('#id_of_a_thing').DataTable({
            pageLength: 5,
            language: {
                search: '',
                searchPlaceholder: "Type to Search..."
            },
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [{
                extend: 'collection',
                text: '<img class="icon-download-svg mb-1 duration-300 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="/../../img/Download-Icon.svg" alt="download">',
                buttons: [
                    'csv',
                    'pdf',
                ]
            }],
        });
```

Where

```
text: '<img class="icon-download-svg mb-1 duration-300 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="/../../img/Download-Icon.svg" alt="download">',
```

becomes

```
text: '<x-svg-comp/>',
```

I'd imagine that Laravel will have a hard time rendering this but maybe someone has something in the back pocket